# Go vet Sprinf checking number of arguments

Tags: go, string-formatting, golangci-lint

I’ve found an interesting behavior of `go vet` with `Sprintf` which I would not expect (it’s
inside the lint check).

Could you explain me why `go vet` is not throwing a violation in the second numbered case (**case 2**)? I’d expect it should also cover this case as developer might forget to update the formatting string. Or, at least to have a possibility to turn this kind of check on by configuration.

Thanks for explanation.

**case 1**: For this check, I get a violation:

```golang
fmt.Sprintf("%[1]s%[2]s", "foo")
```

**case 2:** When I pass more arguments into `Sprintf` than expected, everything is fine from `go vet` perspective:

```golang
fmt.Sprintf("%[1]s", "foo", "bar")
```

**case 3:** When I don't use numbered arguments in this case, I get a violation from `go vet`

```golang
fmt.Sprintf("%s", "foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Numbered format parameters main use case is to *separate* what the format string uses (in whatever order) from the arguments.

Think of translations where you might want to switch the format string from "%[1]s hits %[2]s" to "%[2]s got hit by %[1]s". For this type it often is necessary to *drop* arguments (because you do not need them in the output; think of "%[2] got hit"). Numbered arguments allow to repeat stuff like in "%[1]s foo %[1]s bar %[1]s".

So numbered arguments are about re-ordering, duplicating *and dropping* arguments.
If go vet would warn about unused arguments this main use case of numbered arguments would not work.

Case 1: is a bug because the fmt string requires two arguments.

Case 3: One, single argument required, two given, no intention to resort/regroup/duplicate

Case 2: format string makes clear it likes to re-order, duplicate or drop arguments by using numbered arguments. More arguments given than currently needed: Fine.